# primordial class object in java

Tags: java

I came across a term 'primordial' objects.After searching I got that a primordial class is that class that has no direct super-class For eg Object.  Is this correct?

Also, how can I create a primordial class as every Java class extends from Object class.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't looking for `primordial class loader` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **can't** create a primordial class.

> Excepting Object, which has no superclass, every class has one and only one direct superclass (single inheritance). In the absence of any other explicit superclass, every class is implicitly a subclass of Object.
>
> Classes can be derived from classes that are derived from classes that are derived from classes, and so on, and ultimately derived from the topmost class, Object. Such a class is said to be descended from all the classes in the inheritance chain stretching back to Object.

*http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html*

Answer (score 2):

You can't create a primordial class. **The only primordial class is the Object class**.

And any class that you will declare will automatically inherit from Object.

Answer (score 1):

1. *I came across a term 'primordial' objects.After searching I got that a primordial class is that class that has no direct super-class For eg Object. Is this correct?*

   Yes
2. *how can I create a primordial class as every Java class extends from Object class.*

   As answered by others, you can't create a primordial class. It's already created by Java creators in the form of **Object  class**